# Multiple Modals with same structure on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been exploring how I can make vanilla modals using an example like this codepen: https://codepen.io/brandonb927/pen/wJaIi/ .

The problem with universally every example I've seen is that they relay on targeting class or ID names. I want something where I can have multiple modals like this:

```
<div class="modal">
  <a href="#" class="toggle-modal">Toggle Modal</a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>This is the first modal content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <a href="#" class="toggle-modal">Toggle Modal</a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>This is the second modal content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both of the modals have the exact same class names and formatting but different content. Is it possible to target individual modals like this even when they share the class names? Could you do that with something like javascript "this"?

If you could provide a working snippet, jquery is fine, that would great :D Thanks.

If there is a "modal.js" javascript plugin (preferably jQuery) that lets me accomplish this in a simple way, that would be awesome too. Again, I would appreciate an example though.

Comment: [This is how I would do it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvGbRB?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap does this by specifying a `data-target` property on triggering button. Something like this:

```
<button class="modal-toggle" data-element="two">Show modal 2</button>
```

Where `data-element="two"` points to the modal that is to be shown:

```
<div class="modal" id="two">
```

Now with some minor changes to the `click` event handler you can select the correct modal specified in the `data-element` and show it.

```js
// Quick & dirty toggle to demonstrate modal toggle behavior
$('.modal-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var elementID = $(this).attr("data-element");
  $('.modal#' +elementID ).toggleClass('is-visible');
});

$(".modal-close").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".modal").removeClass("is-visible");
});
```

```css
/**
 * Box model adjustments
 * `border-box`... ALL THE THINGS - http://cbrac.co/RQrDL5
 */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
 * 1. Force a vertical scrollbar - http://cbrac.co/163MspB
 * NOTE: Use `text-rendering` with caution - http://cbrac.co/SJt8p1
 * NOTE: Avoid the webkit anti-aliasing trap - http://cbrac.co/TAdhbH
 * NOTE: IE for Windows Phone 8 ignores `-ms-text-size-adjust` if the
 *       viewport <meta> tag is used - http://cbrac.co/1cFrAvl
 */

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* 1 */
  min-height: 100%;
}

/**
 * 1. Inherits percentage declared on above <html> as base `font-size`
 * 2. Unitless `line-height`, which acts as multiple of base `font-size`
 */

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;   /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.5; /* 2 */
  color: #444;
}

/* Page wrapper */
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Icons */
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  fill: currentcolor;
}

/* Headings */
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: 1.333;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

/**
 * Modals ($modals)
 */

/* 1. Ensure this sits above everything when visible */
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000; /* 1 */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal.is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}

.modal.is-visible .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 6em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32em;
  margin-left: -16em;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
}

.modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.3s 0.12s;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal.is-visible .modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-content {
  padding: 1em;
}

.modal-header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.06);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #aaa;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}

.modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}

.modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.modal-content > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.modal-content > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Simple jQuery Modal</h1>
    <button class="modal-toggle" data-element="one">Show modal 1</button>
    <button class="modal-toggle" data-element="two">Show modal 2</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal" id="one">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
    <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="modal-close modal-toggle"><svg class="icon-close icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg></button>
        <h2 class="modal-heading">This is modal 1.</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit eum delectus, libero, accusantium dolores inventore obcaecati placeat cum sapiente vel laboriosam similique totam id ducimus aperiam, ratione fuga blanditiis maiores.</p>
          <button class="modal-close">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="modal" id="two">
    <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle"></div>
    <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="modal-close modal-toggle"><svg class="icon-close icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg></button>
        <h2 class="modal-heading">This is modal 2.</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit eum delectus, libero, accusantium dolores inventore obcaecati placeat cum sapiente vel laboriosam similique totam id ducimus aperiam, ratione fuga blanditiis maiores.</p>
          <button class="modal-close">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Although this is almost what I want, it isn't exactly. Ideally there would be no defining characteristic per modal, they would look completely identical with the exception of the content which could differ.

Comment: Are you referring to the `id`'s that are different? The other way to do it would be to keep the toggling button and the modal closer to each other. Thus the button only toggles the modal next to it, and not the others. There needs to be a way for the button to know which modal to call, right? As long as you can come up with a rule that allows that, you can write code that does it.

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what I mean. I'm going to try to make your solution work.

Comment: I was able to get it work like intended.... now I just have to understood how modals work in the first place. The css involved is a black box to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) to achieve the desired result with **pure CSS.**

You can add as many modals as you want as long as they have different ids and a button linked to that id.

I use an empty anchor tag with z-index stacking to create a clickable overlay -the dark color behind the modal - which only shows up when the modal is open. Clicking the overlay closes the modal.

The modal also has a separate close button inside.

When the modal is closed it doesn't interfere with the body content.

```js
function newwin() {
  myWindow = window.open('lead_data.php?leadid=1', 'myWin', 'width=400,height=650')
}
```

```css
/* essential code */

a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.closeoverlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closebutton {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal:target>.closeoverlay {
  display: block;
}

.modal>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 75vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #131418;
  z-index: 3
}

.wrap,
.modal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.modal-content {
  overflow-y: auto
}


/*demo fluff */

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}

button {
  margin: 2em 0 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closebutton:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clutter,
.modal-content p {
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.clutter {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#a"><button>Open Modal A</button></a>
  <a href="#b"><button>Open Modal B</button></a>
  <a href="#c"><button>Open Modal C</button></a>
  <a href="#d"><button>Open Modal D</button></a>
  <a href="#e"><button>Open Modal E</button></a>
  <div id="a" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a class="closebutton" href="#">&times;</a>
      <p>Modal A</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="closeoverlay"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a class="closebutton" href="#">&times;</a>
      <p>Modal B</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="closeoverlay"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a class="closebutton" href="#">&times;</a>
      <p>Modal C</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="closeoverlay"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="d" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a class="closebutton" href="#">&times;</a>
      <p>Modal D</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="closeoverlay"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="e" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a class="closebutton" href="#">&times;</a>
      <p>Modal E</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="closeoverlay"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clutter">Bacon ipsum dolor amet shoulder sausage rump venison kevin prosciutto salami shank. Venison salami flank doner burgdoggen, shoulder beef sausage swine alcatra short loin pig chuck. Pastrami sirloin shoulder, swine frankfurter beef strip steak sausage
  salami tri-tip. Prosciutto leberkas boudin pastrami sausage pork. Hamburger pancetta jowl venison pastrami. Filet mignon alcatra burgdoggen salami, ham hock shoulder pork loin sirloin jowl picanha flank drumstick pancetta. Turkey shoulder cupim rump
  ball tip strip steak turducken tri-tip biltong pork doner. Turducken leberkas chuck filet mignon bresaola picanha ball tip pig ground round shankle. Shank pork ribeye fatback, capicola pork loin tri-tip porchetta biltong landjaeger ham hock hamburger.
  Strip steak pork chop sirloin</div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, and I appreciate the fully css version, but what I want are completely identical modals in terms of classes and identifiers. The only differences there should be are in the content, and that should be arbitrary, not identifiers.

I'm fine with adding javascript if it makes this possible.